# Install fonts temporarily

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I would like a program which would do what [AMP Font Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php) does, which is to temporarily install few (or a bunch) fonts from chosen folder, so they could be used by applications (eg. for typesetting) and then again remove them, so they don't slow down the OS and stuff (dunno, how this actually works on Linux, but Windows are slowed on start when they have too many fonts installed).
Is there a way (a rather simple way preferably) to do this?

Comment: I don't think having a lot of fonts slows the system down generally, but it does occasionally slow down programs like LIbreoffice and GIMP, which check for fonts they can use on start (Inkscape used to be especially bad at this, as it did it EVERY TIME it started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install fonts locally in `~/.fonts`. You'll need to create this folder, and you can drop in fonts into that folder. Depending on the program, you may need to restart your computer.

Comment: Won't it slow down the system start-up? Also, the computer restart is what I need to avoid.

Comment: I doubt it. I believe the font will be loaded only if a program wants that font. As for the restarting, note the `may` in my answer. If you're just testing a simple program that you can open/close, then you don't need to restart your computer; you just need to close and reopen that program. If you want to change some font the desktop itself displays, you may need to restart your computer.

Comment: I'm sorry I doubted you :) It works just perfectly. I only need to restart the program when I add a font.
Just for a future reference and inexperienced useres like me - the folder doesn't exist on clean installation, so it has to be created manually.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After years of annoying copying fonts by hand, I finally gave up and wrote my own program for this purpose. I'll be glad if it will be useful for you and other people:

https://danpla.github.io/fontlink